# Drawing horizontal and vertical lines in listview control

Tags: listview, controls

how can I draw horizontal and vertical lines in listview control?

Answer (score 0):

What language are using the listview control in?

If it is in .NET you can just turn on grid lines

```
listView1.GridLines = true;
```

If it's not .NET more info is needed, I used .NET / C# as an example as that is
what I am most familiar with using.